# « [...] to set our own clear and sovereign course / [...] d’établir clairement notre propre orientation souverainiste » : comparaison etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, usage, comparaison-de-langues, politique

Dans un discours<sup>1</sup> l'honorable Chrystia Freeland, ministre des Affaires étrangères du (gouvernement du) Canada, dit ce qui suit en langue anglaise et on a aussi la traduction en français aux *Débats* :

> The fact that our friend and ally has come to question the very worth
>   of its mantle of global leadership puts into sharper focus the need
>   for the rest of us *to set our own clear and sovereign course.* For
>   Canada, that course must be the renewal, indeed the strengthening, of
>   the post-war multilateral order.
>
> ---
>
> Le fait que notre ami et allié met en doute la valeur de son
>   leadership mondial fait ressortir plus nettement le besoin pour le
>   reste d’entre nous *d’établir clairement notre propre orientation
>   souverainiste*. Pour le Canada, cette stratégie doit consister à
>   renouveler, en fait à renforcer, l’ordre multilatéral de
>   l’après-guerre.
>
> [ [*Hansard*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansard#Hansard_au_Canada), Parlement du Canada, 6 juin 2017, 1045 et ss. ([En.](http://www.ourcommons.ca/DocumentViewer/en/42-1/house/sitting-188/hansard#T1045),
>   [Fr.](https://www.noscommunes.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/42-1/chambre/seance-188/debats#T1045)), je souligne. ]

On remarque que dans la version originale en anglais, on a deux adjectifs (*clear and [soverereign](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/sovereign/613555)*) qui s'appliquent au nom [*course*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/course/572825) ; en français on a choisi de faire du premier adjectif un adverbe modifiant le verbe *établir* et d'employer le second avec l'idée d'[*orientation*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/orientation/56479?q=orientation#56144). Sauf que ce n'est pas l'adjectif [*souverain(e)*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souverain), qui qualifie *ce qui possède la souveraineté politique*, qu'on emploie ici mais plutôt l'adjectif (et nom) [*souverainiste*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/souverainiste/74002?q=souverainiste#73172), avec le suffixe en [*-iste*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-iste) amenant l'idée de ce qui « adhère à une doctrine, une croyance, un système, un mode de vie, de pensée ou d'action, ou exprime l'appartenance à ceux-ci » (TLFi), tel le partisan « de l'accession de la province [Québec] au statut d'État souverain » ou « d'une Europe constituée de nations souveraines » (Larousse). Et donc pour moi ce serait généralement associé à l'orientation du partisan, du/de la *souverainiste*, et il m'est fort difficile de faire abstraction du contexte québécois alors j'y vois une analogie...

---

- L'*orientation souverainiste*, est-ce objectivement l'équivalent du
  *sovereign course* ou plus généralement y a-t-il adéquation entre « *to set our own clear and sovereign course* » et sa traduction en français soit « *d’établir clairement notre propre orientation
  souverainiste* » ; pourquoi l'adverbe et l'adjectif dérivé avec
  suffixe au lieu des deux adjectifs ; les mêmes apports de sens
  sont-ils réalisés par des fonctions et des référents différents ?
- L'*orientation souverainiste*, est-ce du vocabulaire de sciences
  politiques ; quel serait l'antonyme d'une orientation souverainiste
  (du gouvernement) d'un état souverain ; une orientation souverainiste
  participe-t-elle du [*souverainisme*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/souverainisme/74001?q=souverainisme#773709) ou du [*nationalisme*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/nationalisme/53867?q=nationalisme#53511)
  ; est-ce qu'à l'extérieur du Canada on en comprend l'idée d'une
  sortie d'un ensemble politique (invisible ?) ou de l'affirmation
  d'une (ou d'un groupe de) nation(s) à l'intérieur d'icelui, voire les
  deux ; a-t-elle une caractère ou une connotation particulière, comme
  la *contrariété*, ou serait-ce plutôt compris comme une allégorie du
  [*multilatéralisme*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/multilat%C3%A9ralisme/53183?q=multilat%C3%A9ralisme#209880) dont on trouve la référence dans la phrase
  qui suit ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Perception aux É.-U. du discours en langue anglaise : [sur *CNN*](http://www.cnn.com/2017/06/10/opinions/diy-foreign-policy-opinion-geltzer-finer/index.html), [*New York Times*](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/12/world/americas/a-canadian-ministers-speech-shows-a-growing-divide-with-the-us.html?mcubz=0), [*Washington Post*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/the_americas/minister-canada-will-build-up-its-military-as-the-us-pulls-back-from-world-stage/2017/06/06/4c841a22-4ad8-11e7-987c-42ab5745db2e_story.html) et [*WP+Bloomberg*](https://washpost.bloomberg.com/Story?docId=1376-OR4RGZ6TTDS001-6957KIO136OB4J5SBEEI833638).</sub>

---

Comment: in English, course means direction of a naval vessel or aircraft. That is the origin of the term: to steer a course, to set a course. Et dans ce sens-là, le terme en français serait: le cap. to set a course=déterminer un cap. Il ne s'agit pas d'une orientation. Et souverainiste me semble erroné, pour le dire gentillement.

Comment: The metaphor here in English is always: the ship of state. The state is compared to ship that has to have its course set before sailing anywhere. The captain sets the course or orders the first mate to set the course [for a particular destination]. Alors, il ne s'agit pas d'orientation mais de direction.

Comment: @AgentBaptiste: Orientation a aussi le sens de "tendance politique", alors une "orientation souverainiste" ne pose pas de problème en soi, mais ici, ce terme ne correspond ni au sens du texte original, ni au contexte du discours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question fort intéressante pour le traducteur que je suis (quoique je travaille présentement principalement du japonais à l'anglais).

Jusqu'au point où le traducteur remplace *clear* par *clairement* et choisit *orientation* pour traduire *course*, je ne vois pas de problème. Toutefois, le choix de *souverainiste*, comme vous le soulignez, est discutable.

Il est très possible, que ce choix laisse transparaître les opinions politiques du traducteur du Hansard, mais il est aussi possible que ce fût un lapsus découlant d'une traduction faite à la hâte et sous pression après en avoir fait plusieurs autres où *souverainiste* était le mot juste.

Je remarque avec intérêt que selon google.ca, certains médias canadien- français ont employé *orientation souveraine* dans ce passage, conservant ainsi une nuance équivalente à celle de l'énoncé original. Je m'avancerais aussi à dire qu'on pourrait parler d'une orientation *indépendante* si l'on interprète le *sovereign* de l'anglais comme un euphémisme qui veut souligner que l'orientation adoptée par le Canada ne devrait pas se décider en fonction de la politique de "notre ami et allié".

Une autre traduction possible, quoiqu'un peu plus lourde, serait *une orientation digne d'un état souverain*, qui rend explicite le message implicite de l'anglais, mais je ne crois pas qu'il soit vraiment nécessaire d'aller jusque là.

Mais pour en revenir au coeur de la question linguistique, je dirais, pour reprendre votre formulation, que les mêmes apports de sens peuvent être apportés par des fonctions et des référents différents, du moins en principe, mais dans ce cas en particulier, cela ne s'applique qu'à la première moité de l'énoncé en raison du glissement de sens dans la deuxième moitié.

Je ne saurais dire si l'expression *orientation souverainiste* est un terme consacré en sciences politiques, mais comme antonyme, j'utiliserais *orientation fédéraliste*, du moins dans un contexte canadien. Dans un contexte politique différent, le terme *unioniste* serait peut-être préférable.

Comment: Ça se dit ça _un choix dubitatif_ ? Cela sonne bizarre à mes oreilles, j'emploierais plutôt _discutable_ à la place.

Comment: @Patsuan je suis d'accord. On aurait aussi pu écrire « un choix douteux ». J'imagine que Philippe avait *dubious* en tête.

Comment: Oui, déterminer un cap digne d'un état souverain et sans ambages.

Comment: I can assure you that orientation souverainiste is really not right here. In any event, in French, iste means like or showing that condition. Sovereign is sovereign, no like, no conditions.

Comment: Pour moi, le mot orientation ici en français serait une gross faute.

Comment: Le "choix dubitatif" était effectivement une erreur, preuve que je ne devrais pas écrire quand il est tard et que je devrais plutôt aller me coucher (d'où, aussi, les trop nombreuses fautes aimablement corrigées par Patsuan)! En ce qui concerne le mot "orientation", s'il n'est peut-être pas le meilleur choix, je ne crois pas que ce soit une "grosse faute" étant donné les sens de "voie choisie..." et "direction..." que donne le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/orientation/56479?q=orientation#56144), acceptations peut-être plus courantes au Canada qu'ailleurs.

Comment: En ce qui concerne "l'orientation souveraine", on retrouve l'expression aux réseaux [Radio Canada](http://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1038268/canada-chrystia-freeland-politique-etrangere-etats-unis-fannie-olivier) et [TVA](http://www.tvanouvelles.ca/2017/06/09/le-secretaire-du-tresor-rejette-lopinion-dune-ministre-canadienne), qui sont probablement les deux principaux réseaux d'information francophones au Canada.

Comment: Il aurait fallu traduire l'expression nautique/maritime /to set a course/ et ne pas utiliser établir une orientation sinon de déterminer un cap. Quant à souverainiste, ça fait mal aux oreilles. Et c'est une faute de traduction.

Answer (score 3):

(Here are two late arriving points that don't really address your good  questions but which I nevertheless felt worthy of mention.  Hopefully my attempt to make these points in French will not render them totally incomprehensible):

---

Je trouve intéressant que les deux instances du mot “course” dans la version originale  sont traduites avec deux mots différents en Français (‘orientation’ d’abord et puis ‘stratégie’).

Bien sur, le mot ‘course’ a/peut avoir plusieurs sens suivant le contexte, mais dans ce contexte-là, où l’instance  de ‘**that** course’ dans la 2eme phrase ne peut faire référence qu’a la première instance du mot, leurs sens doivent, il me semble, être pareils et donc leurs traductions respectives doivent être au moins similaires.

Pour moi, les sens des mots ‘orientation’ et ‘stratégie’ ne sont pas assez similaires pour faire une connexion directe (et logique) entre ‘**cette** stratégie’ et ‘orientation,’ qui me fait croire que l’un des deux (soit ‘orientation’ ou soit ‘stratégie’) n’est pas le mot juste pour capter **ce seul** sens du mot ‘course,’ et entre ces deux mots, je voterais pour ‘stratégie’ pour traduire ces deux instances de ‘course’

Pour arriver a cet opinion, il faut admettre qu’il m’a fallu ajouter [présomptueusement] deux mots a la version originale pour voir  ‘[setting a] course’ plutôt comme ‘[setting/planning/determining a] course **of action**,’ mais je ne pouvais pas le résister car, d’après moi, le mot ‘stratégie’ dans la 2eme phrase capte si bien la notion de ‘course of action.’

---

Pour parler de l’utilisation du mot ‘souverainiste’ (soit avec ‘orientation’/’stratégie’/’cap’/'direction'/etc), je trouve intéressant aussi qu’en parlant de (et aux) ‘the rest of **us**’ (le reste d’entre nous) dans la première phrase (que j’interprète comme ‘tous **les** pays souverains qui peut-être dépend[ai]ent de trop sur le[non]dit ‘ami et allié’), l'honorable Ministre mentionne, **dans le singulier** ...  **one** course [of action], i.e., ‘**our own** clear and sovereign **course**.’

Je ne prends pas cet ‘our own … course’ pour dire ‘Canada’s own singular/particular/souvereign course,’ mais plutôt pour dire ‘**une seule** stratégie/orientation/cap/direction collective pour **tous** ces autres pays’, surtout vu que la Ministre n’a pas dit ‘our own respective/individual [clear and sovereign] course**s**.’

Par contre, c’est dans la 2eme phrase que l’on trouve ce que le Canada va attend et même exiger de cette 'orientation souverainiste' [libre/en dépit des actions de cet ami/allié], et c'est là que la **souveraineté** du Canada et sa stratégie **souveraine**  se manifestent vis-à-vis cette orientation/stratégie souverain**iste**.

Tout ça pour dire que **peut-être**, en parlant des actions/orientations/stratégies/pouvoirs/etc d’un groupe/d’une alliance des pays souverains, la notion de ‘sovereign-like’ ou ‘soveriegnesque’ serait à-propos/relevant ici car en se regroupant les pays souverains en cèdent souvent envers l’alliance/entité souverainiste, mais je crois que les suffixes ‘-istique’ or ‘-esque’ seraient préférables pour faire un tel adjectif pour éviter l’ambiguïté avec le sens ‘partisan’ du mot ‘souverainist/e.’

Comment: Observations intéressantes. Pour ma part, et malgré l'utilisation du singulier, je reste porté à interpreter quand même le premier "our own course" comme "each of us should set his or her own course" puisque même si elle n'a pas dit "courses", elle n'a pas non plus clairement dit "a single course of action for the rest of us", mais votre commentaire donne matière à réflexion. Peut-être qu'elle envisageait des stratégies souveraines individuelles, mais coordonnées pour aller dans des directions compatibles ou au moins complémentaires.